# NTLM instead of Kerberos with Chrome version 69 when using alias in url

Tags: google-chrome, alias, kerberos, ntlm, keytab

Since update to version  69.0.3497.81, kerberos authentication on our application doesn't work anymore. I don't master the authentification process but it seems that chrome use NTLM instead of Kerberos for authentication.

Access url to our application use an alias. Example:

https://myApplication/test

The application is deployed on a server: serverA.domain.com

I think the keytab referenced serverA.domain.com.

I noticed that if I use full server name with domain, it works! -> https://serverA.domain.com/test

We confirm that with previous chrome version, it works.

Have you guys met problems like that with last chrome update ? Any suggestion ?

Comment: Nothing to do with keytabs ; Kerberos requires _canonical_ DNS names by default, and does a DNS lookup then reverse lookup as a protection against IP spoofing.

Comment: you are right. Like I said, I discovered the topic and it's not my domain ;) The problem was that chrome didn't do the resolution of Cnames since last update. A fix is done and will be soon publish toward a new chrome version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a bug on google chrome. Since version 69.0.3497.23, chrome didn't resolve Cnames anymore. So if you use an alias in your DNS, it's not resolved and use directly for negocation kerberos.

chrome than got an error "ERR_ACCESS_DENIED".

With an incorrect SPN, the ticket acquisition will fail. Windows defaults to NTLM in those cases.

More Explanation from bug chat:

"Async host resolver currently doesn't resolve CNAMEs. Thus use of the
async resolver is not currently compatible with the needs of
HttpAuthHandlerNegotiate where correct CNAME lookup is required."

Bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=872665

Hope this help others!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, we have problems like that, it seems to be a bug in the latest version of Chrome, please see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=872665

Comment: You cited the very same bug as Mathieu 2 days earlier.  This answer does not improve on his.